# How to increment the input field names in the middle of them using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, clone

I'm implementing Spring and hibernate project, for that I need to insert multiple rows into database. I've written of the below code in jsp. My senior told that, to seperate it into 3 parts,

```
  irstpart=listOfChannelType[<br/>
  Secondpart=0(it should increment dynamically when i click add button)
  thirdpart=].typeid<br/>
```

I need like this:

```
listOfChannelType[0].typeid<br/>
listOfChannelType[0].typename<br/>

listOfChannelType[1].typeid<br/>
listOfChannelType[1].typename<br/>

listOfChannelType[2].typeid<br/>
listOfChannelType[2].typename<br/>
.<br/>
.<br/>
.<br/>
.<br/>
.<br/>
listOfChannelType[n].typeid<br/>
listOfChannelType[n].typename<br/>
```

**Channel_Type.jsp**

```html
<table id="addRows" width="350px" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="content">

    <tr>
    <td width="19%" align="left">Type ID </td>
    <td width="18%" align="left">Type</td>
    <td width="11%" align="left">
        <input id="addbutton" type="button" value="Add" class="add" />
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="row0" class="add">
    <td width = "33%" align = "left"><s:input path="listOfChannelType[0].typeid" id="typeid"/></td>
    <td align = "left" width = "33%"><s:input path="listOfChannelType[0].typename" id = "typename"/></td>
    <td align = "left" width = "33%"><input type="button" id="btn" name="btn" value="Delete"/></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function(){
  $("input.add").click( function(){
  var $trlast=$("#addRows").find("tr:last");
  var $trnew=$trlast.clone();
  $trlast.after($trnew);
  });  
 $.fn.deleteRow=function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();  
  return this;
  }; 
});
</script>
```

When I click the add the button, it should create another row dynamically and increment the values.! How can I do this in jquery? 
What is the jquery code for this? I've written some jquery code, wich is creating rows but he does not incrementing.
Pls help me with this. 
I'm working as intern in a company and I have to finish this task by end of this week.

Thanks in adavnce

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you really need some css in that table.
Second, this is javascript not php so don't name variables starting with "$". It makes it look like there is jquery everywhere.

You shouldn't need "find" in this line

var $trlast=$("#addRows").find("tr:last");

There are going to be problems if you use an id for each td since an id should be unique, so switch to class or just go on the column headers.

The first row in your table should use "th" instead of "td".

For your delete and add button just use a "button" tag instead of an input tag. This should also use a class instead of an id.

To add a new row you should look at the w3schools' jquery append method http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_append.asp
Then do HTML, CSS, Javascript, Jquery, etc. on there and you'll be way more qualified for your position right now.